# .toArray not workin

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i have more than 20 products on the database and i am trying to display all of them so i used

```
 Product.find({}).toArray(function(err,data){
  if(err){
      res.send(err)
  }
  if(data){
      res.send(data)
  }
 }
```

but i get an error

```
TypeError: Product.find(...).toArray is not a function
```

so then i used

```
Product.find({},function(err,products){
  if(err){
      res.send(err)
  }
  if(products){
      res.send(products)
  }
})
```

but it only prints out 20 products. so then i tried

```
Product.find({},function(err,products){
  if(err){
      res.send(err)
  }
  if(products){
      res.send(products)
  }
}).limit(300)
```

but it still prints out 20 products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use promises instead of using callbacks

Try this:

```
Products.find().then(products => {
  res.send({ products })
}).catch(err => {
  res.send({ err })
})
```

It should retrieve **all** products instead of just 20

If it retrieves just 20, check how much do you have using the .count() method

Answer (score 0):

You should add options like `limit` before the `toArray`-call. Additionally I assume you have a default limit set by your included mongodb library.

This code sample should give you 300 products:

```
Product
 .find({})
 .limit(300)
 .toArray(function(err,data) {
   if (err) {
     res.send(err);
   } else if (data) {
     res.send(data);
   }
)};
```

For reference see [mongodb-native #find](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#find) and/or [mongodb-native Cursor](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Cursor.html)